# regex for certain html links

Tags: python, regex

EDOT: you guys are right, bs4 is much better and have started using it, its much more intuitive and actually finds links 
although I'm still struggling at points haha 
thank you all very much

had a look and this doesnt seem to be in the other posts

so i am pretty sure I can use regex for this as the 15 links in this html page are pretty well defined I think, its an amazon page with 15 product links and I want those links 
 input is this

```
<a href="\n\n\n\n\n\n https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nikon-Coolpix-L340-Bridge-Camera/dp/B00THKEKEQ/ref=zg_bs_560836_2&#10;">Nikon Coolpix L340 Bridge Camera - Bl...</a>
```

I have tried

```
import re

links = re.findall(r'^(/n/n/n/n/n/n).(")', page)
```

which wont work,  any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you using `/n` instead of `\n`?

Comment: That's a weird looking href. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: edit python shell shows
youre right 
href="\n\n\n\n\n\n\n https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sony-DSCW800-Digital-Compact-Optical/dp/B00IK01PJC/ref=zg_bs_560836_1/277-1976309-0409436\n">Sony DSCW800 Digital Compact

either way 

links = re.findall(r'href="(.*?)"', page)

 does not seem to work, which I thought it would given its just supposed to return anything between a href tag and a "

Comment: But for future  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp below:

```
s = """<a href="\n\n\n\n\n\n https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nikon-Coolpix-L340-Bridge-Camera/dp/B00THKEKEQ/ref=zg_bs_560836_2&#10;">Nikon Coolpix L340 Bridge Camera - Bl...</a>"""

re.findall('(?<=\n\n\n\n\n\n)(.*?)"', s)
```

Previous regexp was looking for `\n...` match at the begining of string, not for case when `\n` in the middle of string as in sample string.

Comment: You probably want `.*?` instead of `.*`